# Random test failure with Angular 6 and Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular6

We have observed random karma test in our CI pipeline. In each run different test fails and sometimes it passes, when it fails this error is thrown:

`Uncaught TypeError: params.map is not a function thrown`

Has anybody got affected by something similar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We have find out that it was caused by other component spec. In this component we are using ActivatedRoute, Router and DialogService (from angularx-bootstrap-modal). It seems that this component couldn't be removed before next test or something like that. Out solution for this error, we are calling

`fixture.destroy()`

in `afterEach` in spec that was causing this failure.